# Claim transaction Fail - We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail

Tags: metamask

I am getting the error below when trying to claim my NAVI tokens into my metamask wallet. Gas fees are insanely high and have yet to find a solution: *"We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail"
I do not have any knowledge on coding but I have copied the details below. Any advice would be welcome, thank you in advance.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>MetaMask</title>

<style>
#app-content {
display: flex;
flex-flow: column;
}

#loading__logo {
width: 10rem;
height: 10rem;
align-self: center;
margin: 10rem 0 0 0;
}

#loading__spinner {
width: 2rem;
height: 2rem;
align-self: center;

margin-top: 1rem;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index.css" />
</head>
<body class="notification">
<div id="app-content">
<img
id="loading__logo"
src="./images/logo/metamask-fox.svg"
alt=""
loading="lazy"
/>
<img
id="loading__spinner"
src="./images/spinner.gif"
alt=""
loading="lazy"
/>
</div>
<div id="popover-content"></div>
<script
src="./load-app.js"
type="text/javascript"
charset="utf-8"

async
></script>
</body>
</html>

adding image as well [image]